# How to Pass Parameter from Paginated Report to Dax Measure

Tags: parameters, dax, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a paginated report using a Power BI dataset as the report source. The Power BI dataset has a measure called Starting Balance:

[image]

Within the Power BI dashboard, this works fine. It just grabs the start date from the date slicer.

However, what I'd like to do is allow the user to select the start date from the paginated report and pass that value into the dax measure.

[image]

I've tried researching methods for achieving this, but I'm still new to paginated reports and I'm not sure where to look. Is something like this possible? Is there a better approach?

Comment: I am also trying to do the exact same thing.. Please let me know if find a solution..

Comment: So far the only solution I've come up with is to bring over the entire fact table twice. Once for all dates prior to the start date in order to calculate a starting balance. And once for all dates on or after the start date in order to calculate period activity. Then I used a subreport to get measures from both datasets. But our data goes back 20 years, so it was painfully slow.